# Hide keypad when typing message of mail

Tags: ios

Is any way to hide keypad programmatic (like done button )when after write the text in mail message body

Comment: How one would like to hide keypad when he is writing!! :P BTW `resignFirstResponder` is common solution to hide keypad

Comment: sorry mistake in my question,i need add another button (like Done button )to hide keypad after writing

Comment: Ok. Please rephrase your question accordingly. Add `UIButton` as per your requirement in the view. & inside action method of that button, hide keyboard by checking `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`

Comment: thanks..but if i do like this ,Is any possibilities for app rejection from apple

Comment: yes ,i used MFMailComposeViewcontroller

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21752/discussion-between-user1501566-and-hp-ios-coder)